# http Response android studio cant connect to xamp

Tags: android, connection, httpresponse

my httpresponse can connect to xamp.. it have failed to conncet server !! output with this code

please help me to get solution..

```
package com.zul.app.login;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.h

ttp.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txtUser;
    private EditText txPass;
    private EditText txStatus;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private String url ="http://192.168.42.175/loginandroid/cekuser.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        txPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        txStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.statuslog);
        btnLogin =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btlogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               url = "http://192.168.42.175/loginandroid/cekuser.php";
                url +="?user="+txtUser.getText().toString()+"&pass="+txPass.getText().toString();
                getRequest(txStatus,url);

            };
        });

    };
```

this is my http respon:

```
    public void getRequest(EditText txtResult, String Surl){
        Log.d("getRequest",Surl);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Surl);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            txtResult.setText(request(response));
        }catch (Exception e){
            txtResult.setText("Failed Conect To Server!!");

        };


    };

    private String request(HttpResponse response) {
        String result = "";
        try{
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                str.append(line+"\n");
            }
            in.close();
            result = str.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            result="error";

        };
        return result;
    }
};
```

ihave permission with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

if i run this project i dont have error but can't connect to server or failed to acces my localhost

i have php file with this link loginandroid/cekuser.php

if i use browser in android i can connect to xamp but if i use my project i cant connect

result:

failed to connect server

logcat :

```
08-11 10:50:36.231 19556-19556/com.zul.app.login D/getRequest: http://192.168.42.175/loginandroid/cekuser.php?user=&pass=
08-11 10:50:36.256 19556-19556/com.zul.app.login I/System.out: main calls detatch()
```

Comment: Can you print the `result`?

Comment: Please test your webservice using a tool like postman and check if it gives the expected response

Comment: 08-11 10:50:36.231 19556-19556/com.zul.app.login D/getRequest: http://192.168.42.175/loginandroid/cekuser.php?user=&pass=
08-11 10:50:36.256 19556-19556/com.zul.app.login I/System.out: main calls detatch()  this is the result from logcat. resutlt from android "failed conncect to server"

Comment: i have solution with use syntask to connect to xampp